# How to display Rails development.log nicely to vim/sublime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash, vim, sublimetext

Development.log can be easily read if loaded to `tail` or `cat`. But if it is loaded to `vim` or `sublime` the content has additional escape characters which make it difficult read. e.g.:

```
[1m[35m (0.2ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36m (776.2ms)[0m  [1mCREATE TABLE "accounts" ("id" serial primary key, "user_id" integer, "type" character varying(255), "token" character varying(255), "expired_at" character varying(255), "created_at" timestamp, "updated_at" timestamp) [0m
```

I guess the additional characters are used to set colours in bash. How to display this nicely in `vim` or `sublime`?

Comment: I wi=onder if it has something to do with ecoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, these are ANSI Escape sequences used to switch the color and font attributes in the terminal. As low-level tools like `cat` directly output to the terminal, these print just fine there. But Vim is a text editor, and shows its own rendering of the text, including such special characters (the `<Esc>` usually shows up as `^[`, for example).

If you want to view such log output in Vim, its best to capture it *without* the color information. Some commands support a `--no-color` command-line argument; or try unsetting `TERM` or `TERM=dumb` before launching the command.

Alternatively, the [AnsiEsc.vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=302) can convert the escape sequences to Vim syntax highlighting.

Comment: I tried AnsiEsc, it could change the colour but the escape characters are still there. How to remove them?

Comment: You need a Vim 7.3/4 with the _conceal_ feature to have those hidden away (they will still physically remain in the text); check with `:echo has("conceal")`.

Comment: Previously I used vim 7.3 whose `echo has("conceal")` is 0. After I updated to 7.4, it works. Thx!